# IntelliJ IDEA missing potential NPE warning

Tags: intellij-idea

Consider the following method:

```
void foo(Map<String, String> map) {
    String v = map.get("key");
    if (v == null) {}
    System.out.println(v.toUpperCase());
}
```

IntelliJ (stick stuck on version 14 due to company standard) quite rightly warns me that `v.toUpperCase()` may throw a NullPointerException. But with the following code, i.e. without the `if` statement, there is no warning:

```
void foo(Map<String, String> map) {
    String v = map.get("key");
    System.out.println(v.toUpperCase());
}
```

Is there some configuration that stops it warning of NPE if I don't do an `if` check first? Or has this missed warning been "fixed" in later versions?

Comment: Still the same in latest version, but I don't think that IntelliJ signals all possible null references. I think it only does so when your code somehow indicates that the value might be null, or if the methods that are used have `@Nullable` annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour here is unchanged in version 2018.1.

If you add a null check, the code inspection assumes the variable as [`Nullable`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) and therefore warns you about further unchecked calls on this variable.

You can suppress this by `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`